# Not able to see the contacts registered through the website in required address book in CMS

Tags: 2011, content-delivery, outbound-email

When I am trying to add a new user through website, It succesfully update the SubMgmt database (CDA). Also contact syncronization service is running and it successfully insert the same entry in Tridion_cm_email database (CMS).

I am able to see the contact on CMS side(in Administration tab) under unassigned Contacts address book.

The contact details does not reflect on the address book which I have created for the particuler publication (from which I am registering the contact).

- I have added the URL of register page in Audience Management Tab example. `(http://xxx/Register.aspx)`
- I have assigned the Address book (created for this publication) under Allowed Address book
- Also I have checked the checkbox (Synchronize Address Book) option
- I have also selected the Syncronization Target which I created and contain the following URL`(http://contactsync/Profilesync.aspx)`

Does anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: I'm a bit rusty with AM, but don't you also have to specify which Address Book to use on the register page?

Comment: Thanks but suppose if I specify the address book on register page of website, there is no specific table for address book where I can save the details of the address book. It will ultimately the contact_extended_details. Information will then sync and go to CMS but how the CMS here will know to store this contact information in particular address book. If you have any example please share. I have refered the sample.dll code provided by tridion to implement the AM. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can set the Id of the Addressbook in your Subscribe page
in your code behind on submiting the form, if you do not provide it or an addressbook with that id does not exists, the contact will end up in unassigned contacts

```
protected void SubscribeButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    Contact contact = new Contact();
    contact.EmailAddress = Email.Text;
    contact.SubscriptionStatus = SubscriptionStatus.Subscribed;
    contact.ExtendedDetails["NAME"].Value = FirstName.Text;
    contact.ExtendedDetails["SURNAME"].Value = LastName.Text;
    contact.ExtendedDetails["PASSWORD"].Value = Digests.DigestPassword(Password.Text);

    contact.AddressBookId = 151; //tcm:0-151-196640

    // Pass URI of confirmation page, or empty string if no confirmation should be sent.
    string notificationPageId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Subscribe.NotificationPageId"];
    contact.Save(notificationPageId ?? String.Empty);
}
```